# How to notice log file changes with Linux standard tools?

Tags: scripting, system-calls

I need something that does not need to be installed. It's on an embedded system with very little space on the HD. I can't instal anything. I need to do it with something that is already included.

I have a script that I want to run based on a certain line that appears in a log file. Currenty I placed this script to run every 5 minutes in the crontab and check the file for changes.

Is there a way that I can have the system call the script only if the file has changed? Like, to tell the system to fire the script in case a system call was made to open that file with write permission?

Comment: In fact you should look for inotify questions there's already lot's of them and that's what you're looking for. you can also check this from SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060212/in-linux-how-do-i-run-a-shell-script-when-a-file-or-directory-changes

Comment: That's the kind of thing `fail2ban` does.

Comment: Is the log file directly produced by an application, or is it one of the ones written to by syslog?

Comment: All the answers (as well as the duplicate answers) speak of something that has to be installed. I need something that is included by default in linux. The script I'm trying to run in on an embedded system. I can't install anything.

Comment: @Tom, if the system uses a different `syslog` implementation (most systems will have one unless very rudimentary), maybe there is a way to do it with that. Otherwise if `inotify` is configured in the kernel, a short C program may do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several ways to do it. I often use `iwatch`.

```
$ touch yourfile
$ iwatch -e all_events  yourfile
```

after another touch you'll get

```
[26/Feb/2014 17:02:39] IN_OPEN yourfile
[26/Feb/2014 17:02:39] IN_ATTRIB yourfile
[26/Feb/2014 17:02:39] IN_CLOSE_WRITE yourfile
[26/Feb/2014 17:02:39] * yourfile is closed
[26/Feb/2014 17:02:40] IN_OPEN yourfile
[26/Feb/2014 17:02:40] IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE yourfile
```

You can also exec a desired command if the file changes:

```
 $ iwatch -e modify -c "ls -ls  yourfile" yourfile
```

after a

```
 cat /dev/null > yourfile
```

you'll get

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 26 17:05 yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If the program create the messages logs through `syslog` and your system uses `rsyslog`, you can add a line in `rsyslog.conf` (or add a file in `/etc/rsyslog.d`). Something like:

```
facility.* :msg, isequal, "search line" ^/path/to/script
```

You will need to work out the facility from looking elsewhere in `rsyslog.conf`.